# How many different elements can we obtain by multiplying all element in a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group.

> How many different elements can we obtain by multiplying all element in a group?

Of course, if $G$ is abelian the answer is one but when G is non-abelian, changing the order of the multiplication may produce new elements.

My second question is actually related to my attempt to solve the first one.

> Let $S$ be set of all elements produced by multiplying all elements in $G$. Then, it is easy to show that $Aut(G)$ acts on $S$ naturally. I wonder whether this can be transitive.

Comment: If $|G|=n$ then there is $n!$ ways to multiply the elements of $G$ now among these $n!$ elements there must be equal elements as we can't exceed the number of elements of $G$ whic is exactly $n$.

Comment: Cool question! As you said, in an abelian group, $|S|=1$, but I don't know the answer in general. Do you allow only products of all elements where each element appears exactly once? Did you try to see what happens in the case of, say, $S_3$?

Comment: @5xum Not necessarily $S=\{1\}$, only $|S|=1$. Check with $G=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen correction noted.

Comment: There are already $n$ repetitions corresponding to the different $n=|G|$ possible positions of $1_G$. You can generalize this by looking to the center of $G$ which is composed of the elements of $G$ that commute with all other elements.

Comment: With $G=S_3$ the answer is $S_3\setminus A_3$, i.e. the set of 2-cycles, $S=\{(1\,2),(1\,3),(2\,3)\}$. One inclusion is clear as the product is always an odd permutation. The other follows by symmetry.

Comment: Small subcase: If $x^2\neq e$ for all $x\neq e$ every element has a distinct inverse, so pick any $g\in G$ such that we can find $h,k$ with  $g=hkh^{-1}k^{-1}$. Multiply this by the rest of the elements in the order $aa^{-1}$ and we can get all $g$ of this form.

Comment: @DavidPeterson aka. $|G|$ is odd

Comment: 5xum; Yes every element appears exactly one.I have not tried it for  $S_3$ since 120 differnt way exists(6-1)!(exclude idendity).it may be done by help of computer.

Comment: With $G=S_n$, $n>3$ we have $S\subseteq A_n$ because the products must be even permutations (there is an even number of odd perumtations in $S_n$).

Comment: @DavidPeterson ,Does it mean that when |G| is odd, $S=G^{'}$

Comment: @mesel $G'$ is the group *generated* by the commutators. David has only shown that $S$ contains at least the *set* of commutators (and also "disjoint" products of commutators).

Comment: yes,you are right.

Comment: Conversely, if $|S|=1$ is $G$ necessarily abelian?

Comment: @mesel Yes, because that implies $xy\text{(rest)}=yx\text{(rest)}$.

Comment: With a bit of work one can see that $G=S_4$ leads to $S=A_4$. In this case the operation is *not* transitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All products are equal modulo the commutator subgroup, so $S$ is contained in a coset of $G'$. It turns out that $S$ is equal to this coset:

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304020808732572

So the answer is $|G'|$.

Comment: Can I have $31.50 to see the rest of the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidPeterson No you can't. But you can visit http://books.google.com/books?id=UywypI5sjvgC&pg=PA105&lpg=PA105&dq=On+the+Product+of+All+Elements+in+a+Finite+Group+denes+hermann&source=bl&ots=uLmTxTGW-j&sig=qFipKLuCzmWm6dgA3tIdKnSCCbE&hl=tr&sa=X&ei=XgIAU8etFITuyAHvj4FI&ved=0CIEBEOgBMAg#v=onepage&q=On%20the%20Product%20of%20All%20Elements%20in%20a%20Finite%20Group%20denes%20hermann&f=false

Comment: To summarize (and assuming the links are not necessarily perennial): answering a question of L. Fuchs, J. Denes and P. Hermann proved (Annals of Discrete Math. 15 (1982) 105-109) that the set $S$ is equal to a coset of $G'$ for every finite group $G$.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your question is even more subtle. The set of all the possible products is always a coset of the commutator subgroup.

**Theorem** Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$, say $G=\{g_1, \dots, g_n\}$ and let $P(G)=\{g_{\sigma(1)}\cdot g_{\sigma(2)} \dots g_{\sigma({n-1})} \cdot g_{\sigma(n)}: \sigma \in S_n\}$.

(a) If $|G|$ is odd, then $P(G)=G'$

(b) If $|G|$ is even, let $S \in Syl_2(G)$. Then $P(G)=G'$ in case $S$ is *non-cyclic*. If $S$ is cyclic, then $P(G)=xG'$, where $x$ is the unique element of order $2$ of $S$.

This higly non-trivial and beautiful result relates to combinatorics - the construction of Latin Squares. It heavily relies on the proof of the so-called Hall-Paige conjecture (Hall, Marshall; Paige, L. J. *Complete mappings of finite groups*. Pacific Journal of Mathematics **5** (1955), no. 4, 541--549.). This could be proved thanks to the classification of the finite simple groups.