# How many elements can we obtain by that way?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group with $n$ elements with initial order $g_1,g_2,...,g_n$ and let's create the group multiplication table of $G$ with this initial order.

In that table you will have $n$ rows and every element appear exactly one time in one row.

Let $s_i$ be the product of elements of the $i$th row in the order of rows.

The question is how many different $s_i$ can we obtain ?

My motivation depends on this  [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677688/how-many-different-element-can-we-obtain-by-multiplying-all-element-in-a-group) and its answer is $|G'|$, i.e., the number of elements of the commutator group. Thus, in our case this number can be at most $|G'|$.

I also have doubt that whether this number depends on initial order of the elements of $G$ or not.

Thanks.

**Edit:** For $G=S_3$ answer is $3=|G'|$ which is the upper bound.

Comment: Have you had a look at the paper cited in the question? I mean, the questions are identical up to something resembling conjugacy and they might mention conjugacy in the paper. It is, perhaps, non-trivial to work out one from the other (it depends if any of the elements you obtain this way are conjugate or not), but it is, perhaps, worthwhile looking at the paper. Or even just trying to solve the original problem up to conjugacy (which seems easier).

Comment: I read the paper, In paper it has been proved that if we have all possible permutation of products $g_1...g_n$ we get the set $G'$ or 
$aG'$ in both case we have $|G'|$ different elements. After reading the paper, I wonder instead of all permutation, if we take the permutation induced from the left multiplication by the elements of $G$, what is the result ?

Answer (score 0):

I guessed as you did that this does depend on the ordering of the $g_i$ and ran a program to check. I found (if I have not made a error) that the number of $s_i$ may differ. In the dihedral group $D_4$, with the following ordering

()

(2,4)

(1,2)(3,4)

(1,2,3,4)

(1,3)

(1,3)(2,4)

(1,4,3,2)

(1,4)(2,3)

switching the last two elements changes the number of $s_i$ from 1 to 2. That being said, I would guess that there is enough "wiggle room" that one cannot say much more than the number of distinct $s_i$ lies somewhere in 1 and $|G'|$, though it would be relatively interesting if this were not the case.